# IE9 Facebook Like Button Red

Tags: html, css, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button in a hidden modal div which when a user clicks a button that modal appears.

Unfortunately the facebook button that appears has a red rectangle on it, see below:

[image: red facebook like]

I am using IE9 (this issue does not appear in other browsers).

Why on earth does this happen? Is there any way i can solve this while still keeping my modal div hidden?

Comment: can you please provide the code you used?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools window.

Click the 'Select element by click' icon, then click on your Like button.

Now examine the Style window (from bottom to top) to see what's applying a red border.